# Como faço pra acessar esse Json?

Tags: javascript, json

```
{
    "success": {
    "data": [
      {
        "IdContribuinte": "1",
        "IdContribuinteTributario": "1",
        "IdUsuarioAnalisando": null,
        "DataAtualizacaoTributario": null,
        "DataImportacao": "2018-01-12 14:09:26.507",
        "Nivel": "0",
        "Status": "AN",
        "StatusDescricao": "ANALISAR",
        "TipoPessoa": "J",
        "TipoPessoaDescricao": "JURÍDICA",
        "Nome": "PREFEITURA MUNICIPAL DE MARILIA",
        "CpfCnpj": "44.477.909/0001-00",
        "RgIe": null,
        "DataNascimento": null,
        "DataFalecimento": null,
        "Falecido": "0",
        "NomeMae": null,
        "Cep": "17501-900",
        "Endereco": "RUA BAHIA, 40 ",
        "Logradouro": "RUA BAHIA",
        "Numero": "40",
        "Complemento": "",
        "Bairro": "MARÍLIA",
        "Cidade": "MARILIA",
        "Uf": "SP",
        "Telefone": "3402-6000",
        "Email": null,
        "UsuarioAnalisando": null
      },
      {
        "IdContribuinte": "2",
        "IdContribuinteTributario": "100000",
        "IdUsuarioAnalisando": null,
        "DataAtualizacaoTributario": null,
        "DataImportacao": "2018-01-12 14:09:26.507",
        "Nivel": "0",
        "Status": "AN",
        "StatusDescricao": "ANALISAR",
        "TipoPessoa": "F",
        "TipoPessoaDescricao": "FÍSICA",
        "Nome": "JOSE ALVES FILHO",
        "CpfCnpj": "791.910.028-34",
        "RgIe": "9930556",
        "DataNascimento": null,
        "DataFalecimento": null,
        "Falecido": "0",
        "NomeMae": null,
        "Cep": "17522-270",
        "Endereco": "RUA EDUARDO PRADO, 279 ",
        "Logradouro": "RUA EDUARDO PRADO",
        "Numero": "279",
        "Complemento": "",
        "Bairro": null,
        "Cidade": "MARILIA",
        "Uf": "SP",
        "Telefone": null,
        "Email": null,
        "UsuarioAnalisando": null
      }
    ]
    "feedback_msg" => "successo"
}
```

Quero acessar esse json, recebo ele de uma prop do react,

```
const list = this.props.list || []
console.log(list.success.data[0].Nome)
```

mas não estou conseguindo acessar

Comment: O que está sendo retornado aqui: `console.log(list.success.data[0].Nome)`?

Comment: esta retornando isso aqui

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at ContribuintesList.renderRows (app.js:40511)
    at ContribuintesList.render (app.js:40553)
    at app.js:24050
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (app.js:23329)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (app.js:24049)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._renderValidatedComponent (app.js:24076)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (app.js:23616)

Comment: Se eu usar console.log(list.success), ele retorna isso abaixo
{data: Array(100), feedback_msg: null}
data
:
Array(100)
0
:
{IdContribuinte: "1", IdContribuinteTributario: "1", IdUsuarioAnalisando: null, DataAtualizacaoTributario: null, DataImportacao: "2018-01-12 14:09:26.507", …}
1
:

Comment: E se você usar `console.log(list.success.data)`?

Comment: tentei ja, app.js:40511 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Comment: `console.log(list)` dá o que exatamente ? Não estará a apanhar o `[]` que vem do `||` ?

Comment: É a minha primeira pergunta, então fico um pouco perdido na hora de digirar os codigos, mas o meu json é esse aqui, que passo do back end para o front

$result = ['success' => [
            'data' => $recadastramentoImovel,
            'feedback_msg' => 'Registros de contribuintes para o recadastramento'
        ]];

Comment: Esse JSON é inválido.

Comment: Se você controla o backend e tem o código que gera o JSON coloque-o também na pergunta pois é relevante. Assim como o @ValdeirPsr indicou, o JSON que tem na pergunta é invalido, logo o problema começa ai

Comment: eu to recebendo ele normal no front, eu acesso, this.props.list.success ele functiona,

se eu ponho .data ele não funciona

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(action.payload.data.success.data[0])
const INITIAL_STATE = {list: []}
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'CONTRIBUINTES_FETCHED':
        console.log(action.payload.data.success.data[0])
        return { ...state, list: action.payload.data.success }
        default:
        return state
    }
}
```

Eu consegui o acesso, mais dentro do arquivo contribuinteReducer
Eu estava tentando acessar dentro do contribuinte.jsx recebendo o objeto pelo props.